# How to fix TypeScript from throwing error on localstorage.get

Tags: typescript

I recently updated all my packages.json to the latest version on a project including all the TypeScript definitions.

I use to have this in my code:

```
import ls from 'local-storage';
ls.set('userInfo', user);
```

and it worked with no error.

Now, I get the typescript error

```
Property 'get' does not exist on type '<T>(key: string, value?: T | undefined) => void'.
```

I can't figure out what is causing this to happen now.

Edit: One I drill into the type file, I get this.  It seems like my .get is defined

```
    declare module "local-storage" {
        export function set<T>(key: string, value: T): boolean;
        export function get<T>(key: string): T;
        export function remove(key: string): void;
        export function clear(): void;

        export function on<T>(key: string, cb: (value: T) => void): void;
        export function on<T>(key: string, cb: (value: T, old: T) => void): void;
        export function on<T>(key: string, cb: (value: T, old: T, url: string) => void): void;

        export function off<T>(key: string, cb: (value: T) => void): void;
        export function off<T>(key: string, cb: (value: T, old: T) => void): void;
        export function off<T>(key: string, cb: (value: T, old: T, url: string) => void): void;
        export default function <T>(key: string, value?: T): void;
    }
```

Comment: How is your `user` variable defined?

Comment: The code you've shown uses `set`, not `get`, and standard local storage doesn't have `get` or `set` methods; it has `getItem` and `setItem`. What is this `local-storage` you're importing?

Comment: I meant 'set' in all references. I get the same errors on set and get.  user is defined as a typescript interface. local-storage is the npm package local-storage